mutate dynamically sized vec in parallel
I'm trying to mutate a dynamically sized (i.e. under certain conditions, new values are pushed, and pop() gets called in every iteration) Vec in parallel.  Am I doing anything wrong in this working code that does what I need?
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let v0 = Arc::new(Mutex::new((0..=344).collect::<Vec<u32>>()));
    let mut handles = vec![];
    println!("v: {:?}", &v0.lock().unwrap());

    loop {
        let v = Arc::clone(&v0);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut v_guard = v.lock().unwrap();
            if let Some(x) = v_guard.pop() {
                println!("{x}");
                if x == 3 || x == 4 {
                    v_guard.push(666);
                }
            }
        });

        if Arc::clone(&v0).lock().unwrap().is_empty() {
            break;
        }

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("v: {:?}", &v0.lock().unwrap());
}

This example is a simplistic equivalent of what I'm trying to do to parallelize this loop

Yes, your code is not parallel at all, each thread holds the lock for it's entire duration. It is completely sound though. See this Playground and observe that each thread leaves before any other thread enters.

The algorithm also can't really be concurrent since it needs to pop, from a sequence, and that's going to be the vast majority of the work. Well actually the vast majority of the work is the time spent spawning new threads, since you're spawning 344 threads and that's a lot more expensive than popping an integer from a vec.

This is an example that illustrates what I'm trying to do.  The actual Vec I'm using contains a custom type that is much more complex than u32.

Given that we don't know what you're actually trying to do (you haven't told us) this question is probably unanswerable as-is. There may be a better way to do what you're trying to do but we've no idea what that is.

@cdhowie, I'm trying to parallelize this loop

In your application, does the order of operation matter?

@Chad It sounds like channels might be a better approach then, assuming that the order in which the tasks are processed is not critical.

Here's what I came up with that does a scaled down version of what I need.
Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "parallelism"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
directories = "5.0.1"
eng_fmt = "0.1.2"
fastsim-core = { git = "https://github.com/NREL/fastsim.git", branch = "f2/vehicle-in-resources" }
lazy_static = "1.5.0"
rayon = "1.10.0"

src/main.rs
use eng_fmt::FormatEng;
use fastsim_core::traits::SerdeAPI;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use rayon::scope;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let t_ser = super_serial();
    let t_par = par_with_scope();
    println!(
        "Time ratio (should be >1): {}",
        ((t_ser.as_millis() as f64) / (t_par.as_millis() as f64)).format_eng(None)
    );
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref V: Vec<u64> = (0..=10).collect::<Vec<u64>>();
}

fn super_serial() -> std::time::Duration {
    println!("\nstarting series iteration");
    let t_ser_start = Instant::now();
    let mut v = V.clone();
    println!("Vec: {:?}", v);

    loop {
        for x in v.iter_mut() {
            manipulate_x(x);
            cpu_ballast();
        }
        v.pop();
        if v.is_empty() {
            break;
        }
    }
    let t_ser_delta = t_ser_start.elapsed();

    println!("Vec: {:?}", v);
    println!(
        "elapsed time: {} ms",
        (t_ser_delta.as_millis() as f64).format_eng(None)
    );
    t_ser_delta
}

fn par_with_scope() -> std::time::Duration {
    println!("\nstarting parallel iteration");
    let t = Instant::now();
    let mut v = V.clone();
    println!("Vec: {:?}", v);

    loop {
        scope(|s| {
            for x in v.iter_mut() {
                s.spawn(move |_| {
                    manipulate_x(x);
                    cpu_ballast();
                });
            }
        });
        v.pop();
        if v.is_empty() {
            break;
        }
    }
    let t_delta = t.elapsed();

    println!("Vec: {:?}", v);
    println!(
        "elapsed time: {} ms",
        (t_delta.as_millis() as f64).format_eng(None)
    );
    t_delta
}

fn manipulate_x(x: &mut u64) {
    *x *= 2
}

fn cpu_ballast() {
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let mut sd = fastsim_core::simdrive::RustSimDrive::new(CYC.clone(), VEH.clone());
        sd.sim_drive(None, None).unwrap();
        assert!(sd.fc_kw_out_ach.iter().any(|x| *x > 0.));
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref CYC: fastsim_core::cycle::RustCycle =
        fastsim_core::cycle::RustCycle::from_resource("udds.csv", false).unwrap();
    static ref VEH: fastsim_core::vehicle::RustVehicle =
        fastsim_core::vehicle::RustVehicle::from_resource(
            "2017_Toyota_Highlander_3.5_L.yaml",
            false
        )
        .unwrap();
}


Does each thread you spawn require a mutable reference to the Vec<_> or just the item (u32 here)?
if you need the mutable reference to Vec<_>, as other comments. already pointed out it can't really be parallelized, since each thread will need to wait for the mutex, it will just be the same as doing it all in sync.
However, if the spawned task only required the item(u32 here), then you don't need a mutex, you can just pop and spawn thread in the main thread and pass the item to the child thread.
Playground
fn parallize(mut task: Vec<u32>) {
    let mut threads = vec![];

    let t0 = std::time::Instant::now();
    while let Some(u) = task.pop() {

        let t = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("starting task {}", u);
            // some time consuming task here
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs((u % 10).into()));
            println!("finished task {}", u);
        });
        
        threads.push(t);

        if u == 3 || u == 4 {
            task.push(666);
        }
    }
    let dt1=  t0.elapsed();

    for t in threads {
        t.join().unwrap();
    }
    let dt2=  t0.elapsed();

    println!("Time to spawn all task  : {}ms", dt1.as_millis());
    println!("Time to finish all task : {}ms", dt2.as_millis());
}

fn main() {
    let task = (0..=334).collect();
    parallize(task);
}

Output
starting task 331
starting task 329
starting task 328
starting task 319
starting task 323
starting task 326
starting task 321
starting task 322
starting task 320
finished task 320
starting task 324
starting task 325
starting task 327
.
.
.
finished task 29
finished task 9
finished task 19
finished task 49
finished task 39
Time to spawn all task  : 99ms
Time to finish all task : 9126ms

Edit
If the appended task is depend on the child thread computation, you do what you did, but don't hold the guard for the whole lifetime of the thread
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn parallize(task: Vec<u32>) {
    let task = Arc::new(Mutex::new(task));

    let mut threads = vec![];

    let t0 = std::time::Instant::now();
    while let Some(u) = task.lock().unwrap().pop() {
        let task = task.clone();
        let t = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("starting task {}", u);
            if u == 3 || u == 4 {
                task.lock().unwrap().push(666);
            }
            // some time consuming task here
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs((u % 10).into()));
            println!("finished task {}", u);
        });
        
        threads.push(t);
    }
    let dt1=  t0.elapsed();

    for t in threads {
        t.join().unwrap();
    }
    let dt2=  t0.elapsed();

    println!("Time to spawn all task  : {}ms", dt1.as_millis());
    println!("Time to finish all task : {}ms", dt2.as_millis());
}

fn main() {
    let task = (0..=334).collect();
    parallize(task);
}

